# Replace subset of boolean Series with another Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given two boolean pandas Series, say `s` and `t`, how can we replace a subset of `s` with values in `t`?

Example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([True, False, False, True, True, False])
>>> t = pd.Series([True, True, False])
>>> s
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
>>> t
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Expected output on replacing `False` in `s` values with `t`:

```
>>> s
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Namely, indexes in `s` with value as `False` , that is, `[1, 2, 5]` values are replaced with `[True, True, False]`, that is, `t`.

I attempted the following to replace values using boolean masking but was not successful.

```
>>> s[~s] = t
>>> s
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5      NaN
dtype: object
```

Using `s.mask(~s, t)` returns similar result. Why do I get a NaN at index 5 and who do these not work?

While choosing a subset using iloc and then replacing works, this seems like a round-about way of achieving this and I am hoping there is a more clean way to this. Is there one?

```
>>> s.iloc[s[~s].index] = t
>>> s
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that pandas uses the index to realign the series.

You need to use an array:

```
s[~s] = t.values

# or
s[~s] = t.to_numpy()
```

Note that `t` needs to have the same shape as the number of `False` in `s`.

If this is not the case, use:

```
s[s[~s].index[:len(t)]] = t.to_numpy()[:sum(~s)]

# Or

m = ~s
s[m] = pd.Series(dict(zip(s.index[m], t)))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```